# How to include square brackets and equals symbols in TinyMCE code

Tags: angular, tinymce

I want to save code like

```
<app-element [item] = "item"></app-element>
```

However, each time I save this code TinyMCE changes the markup to:

```
<app-element item "" item""></app-element>.
```

Is there a way to do this? My valid elements are '*[*]'.

Comment: what is your editor ?

Comment: As the  title indicates: tinymce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can likely use the protect configuration option to tell TinyMCE to keep the code as you want:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#protect

From the documentation:

> This configuration option enables you to control what contents should
> be protected from editing while it gets passed into the editor. This
> could, for example, be control codes in the HTML. It’s recommended not
> to use inline control contents since it breaks the WYSIWYG editing
> concept, but sometimes they can’t be avoided.
>
> The option takes an array of regular expression that it will match the
> contents against and these will be invisible while editing.